# Помощь с LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

С помощью оператора LEFT JOIN я цепляю вторую таблицу, и соответственно, где связи нет, он возвращает пустое значение. В выборке у меня около 10000 записей и около 3 записей как раз с пустыми значениями. Меня интересуют как раз эти три записи. Почитал про outer join. Так и не понял, работает ли он корректно или нет.

Comment: Покажите что вы делаете...... и структуру таблиц и что нужно получить..... может вам и джойн то не нужен

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, но уже решил задачу, просто использовал условие
  IS NULL

Comment: Ну джойнить таблицу с 10к записей, чтоб выбрать три пустые - как-то не очень правильно...

Comment: Если нашли ответ, то добавте с низу.  Или удалите вопрос.